# How to remove folder and check the execution is completed or not?

Tags: powershell

I am using the below code to delete folder with files:

```
Remove-Item -path D:\Testing\software\program files -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Which is successfully delete folder. When I run this script i want to show that folder deletion successfully completed or not.

Please guide me your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the folder is still present using the `Test-Path` cmdlet:

```
if (Test-Path "D:\Testing\software\program files")
{
   Write-Host "Folder is NOT deleted"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Folder is deleted"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin Brandl. I need to run this script after the remove-item execution. right?